# Rails simple form to show a particular record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make a very simple Go To form.  You enter the id of a `workorder` and it goes to that record's `show` page.

This is the form so far:

```
<%= form_tag workorders_path, :action => 'show' do %>
<p>
  <%= text_field_tag :id, params[:id] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Go To", :name => nil %>
```

This is the show section in the controller:

```
# GET /workorders/1
# GET /workorders/1.json
def show
  @workorder = Workorder.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @workorder }
  end
end
```

I's going to the new workorder screen instead of the show screen.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you should define the show action in your routes

Comment: Can you show your routes.rb file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your URL you need to give id as well, without this id you cannot hit show, and this can only be achieved by using javascript. Here is what you need to add in your js file

```
$(your_submit_tag_id).click(function(e){
  window.location = "your_app_url/workorder/ " + $(#id).val()});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use object method for just showing the record as

f.object.id

f.object.name

where f.object gives the active_record whereas f gives simple_form_builder